# In mongodb, with individual and non-related data among clients. 1- Is it better to have one DB per client or 2- only one DB for all and query data?

Tags: database, mongodb, vue.js, authentication, authorization

This is the scenario:

I am developing a clinic management sofwate in vue, nodejs and mongodb, which each account (each client) may have their own data with their own users and their own patients in their page after they login. Shall I use a separate DB for each client or store everything in one DB and query all data from all the clients in every request ? I searched a lot but couldn't find a clue about which way to go .

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, yes, separated DB(s) per customer is the best solution in the long run.
In your main administrative DB you can map customers to DB-servers giving you a lot of flexibility, for example to give more resources to big customers without impacting small ones.

Also consider using `storage.directoryPerDB:true` config option to reclaim disk space after deleting a DB (trial expired customer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But just to make it clear and of real use case. Could you detail and provide a code example of how one's could achieve this step  you mentioned: "In your main administrative DB you can map customers to DB-servers" . ?